# run useLayoutEffect from parent to child

Tags: reactjs

I like to read a css custom property from a child, which is set by a class which is set by parent component.

The problem is that the useLayoutEffect of the child component runs before the useLayoutEffect of the parent.

Is there a way to change the order of useLayoutEffect or is there another effect which runs in another order? If I use useEffect in Child it is working but there is color flickering.

```js
function App(){
  return <Theme theme="red">
    <Child />
  </Theme>
}

function Theme({theme, children}){
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add(theme);
    return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove(theme);
    }
  },[theme]);
  return children;
}

function Child(){
let ref = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let color = window.getComputedStyle(ref.current).getPropertyValue("--primaryColor");
    
    //TODO: do some color calculations
    
    ref.current.style.background = color;
  });
  
  return <div ref={ref}>content</div>
}
```

```css
body.red {
  --primaryColor: red;
}
```

Comment: https://nicholaslyz.com/blog/2021/06/20/the-uselayouteffect-hook/

Comment: Thank you, I am already using useLayoutEffect